# Internet explorer 8 refuses to download a file from a popup

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, download, popup

I'm crafting a website. In one place there is a button which performs an Ajax callback, and then tries to download a file via `window.open()`. The expected behaviour is for the new window to flash briefly and then a file download to appear. This works fine on IE9, but IE8 seems to have a problem with that, even with popup blocker disabled.

After further experimenting I found another peculiar behavior. If I enter the URL of the download manually into the addressbar of a freshly opened tab, I get an error message. Something generic about not being able to download. If I now try to refresh the page (or just hit ENTER in the address bar, thereby repeating the same request), the download proceeds nicely.

I expected that it might have something to do with `content-disposition` or `cache-control` headers, but removing those didn't help. Nor did adding the URL to the "trusted sites" zone.

I'm going to try and remake it with `window.location` instead anyway, because I don't like the popup (that wasn't made by me), but I'm puzzled about this behavior. What causes it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue.  It turns out that IE has trouble opening files when you use AJAX to get them.  The solution I used is to not use ajax.  Instead I used a little jQuery and a `iframe`:

```
jquery - on click (dont need ajax/get)

            var dynamicUrl = 'SomeFileService.aspx?someQueryParam=' + input;
            $('#iframePopup').attr('src', dynamicUrl);
            window.frames["#iframePopup"].location.reload();

HTML

<iframe id="iframePopup" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely certain we're on the same page here. How do you get a file via AJAX? I meant that when the AJAX request completes, I open a popup window in it's Success event. Anyways, the AJAX request is required to generate the URL.

Comment: @Vilx - Ok I see.  1.  Did you set  `Response.Charset = "";` for aspx or if not .NET, what is the value of `content-type:`?  2.  Did you verify the success callback is performed by simply displaying an `alert`?  3.  Please use  `Fiddler` or something similar to view the HTTP error code when it fails on attempt one.  Also, tell us if this is using NTLM authentication please.